# Vuetify 3 tabs switching transition works only in one direction

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

For some reason, the animation of tabs switching (slider moving) works incorrectly. It moves with transition to the left but without transition to the right.

[image: vuetify transition behaviour]

I have a Vue 3 project created using CLI 5.

I see this problem on my local machine. But when I checked it in web sandbox everything looked OK.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/relaxed-ace-qpr7jt)

[Repository I work locally with](https://github.com/mlukianovich/vuetify-transition-test)

The same behaviour I see creating the Vue 3 project with Vite.

My dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuetify": "^3.4.8",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vuejs-accessibility": "^1.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0"
  }
```

main.js

```
// Vuetify
import 'vuetify/styles';
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
import * as components from 'vuetify/components';
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives';

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
});

createApp(App).use(vuetify)
  .mount('#app');
```

Do you have any ideas about what may be configured wrong?

I noticed this while working on a work project.. I've already tried to create new projects and configure Vuetify from scratch. But without success.
I don't see any appropriate props in the Vuetify documentation that could manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch! I have to do a lot of things to find the answer.

Your project is good and **this seems to be a global** problem related to vuetify, but it is not.

It seems that the **vue version you have is the issue.**
To **fix your problem** you can updgrade your vue version to:

```
"vue": "3.3.9",
```

Maybe the **vue version erase the vuetify class**, i will not search in each changelog to see what happened.

If you need another version of vue, you can downgrade and see if the tabs switch still works.